# Lua 5.0 - iterations over tables ignore duplicate keys even though values are different

Tags: lua

Reading the injected comments in the Code Snippet should give enough context.

```
   --| Table |--
    QuestData = {
        ["QuestName"]={
            ["Quest Descrip"]={8,1686192712},
            ["Quest Descrip"]={32,1686193248},
            ["Quest Descrip"]={0,2965579272},
        },
    }


--| Code Snippet |--
--| gets QuestName then does below |--

    if QuestName then
        -- (K = QuestName) and (V = the 3 entries below it in the table)
        for k,v in pairs(QuestData) do
            -- Checks to make sure the external function that obtained the QuestName matches what is in the table before cont
            if strlower(k) == strlower(QuestName) then
                local index = 0
                -- Iterates over the first two pairs - Quest Descrip key and values
                for kk,vv in pairs(v) do
                    index = index + 1
                end
                -- Iterates over the second two pairs of values
                if index == 1 then
                    for kk,vv in pairs(v) do
                        -- Sends the 10 digit hash number to the function
                        Quest:Function(vv[2])
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

The issue I'm running into is that Lua will only pick up one of the numbers and ignore the rest. I need all the possible hash numbers regardless of duplicates. The QuestData table ("database") has well over 10,000 entries. I'm not going to go through all of them and remove the duplicates. Besides, the duplicates are there because the same quest can be picked up in more than one location in the game. It's not a duplicate quest but it has a different hash number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Key* is always *unique*. It is the *point* of the key, that the key is pointing to unique value and you can't have more keys with same name to point different values. It is by definition by Lua tables.

It is like if you would want to have two variables with same name and different content. It does not make sense ...

> The table type implements **associative arrays**. [...]
>
> Like global variables, table fields evaluate to nil if they are not initialized. Also like global variables, you can assign nil to a table field to delete it. That is not a coincidence: *Lua stores global variables in ordinary tables.*

Quote from [Lua Tables](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html)

---

## Hashing in Lua

Based on comments, I update the answer to give some idea about hashing.

You are using hashing usually in low-level languages like C. In Lua, the associative arrays are already hashed somehow in the background, so it will be overkill (especially using SHA or so).

Instead of linked lists commonly used in C, you should just construct more levels of tables to handle collisions (there is nothing "better" in Lua).

And if you want to have it fancy set up some metatables to make it somehow transparent. But from your question, it is really not clear how your data look like and what you really want.

Basically you don't need more than this:

```
QuestData = {
    ["QuestName"]={
        ["Quest Descrip"]={
            {8,1686192712},
            {32,1686193248},
            {0,2965579272},
         },
    },
}
```

Comment: I know all that. :) I was just trying to keep my question as short as possible without having to go into unnecessary detail. I was hoping someone could tell me if there is a "loop hole" of sorts and iterate the table entries backwards? Or ignore the Quest Descrip key completely and just get the 10 digit hash numbers. I'm not interested in the rest of the keys as this particular function only needs the quest hashes. I didn't design the "database" layout, I'm forced to work with what i got. This function isn't in an OnUpdate loop so it won't constantly run. Efficiency isn't an issue.

Comment: So next time please make sure it makes sense what you write. Your title and first loads of sights on the code and question seems like you totally don't understand concept of associative arrays. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Jakuje, good point. I was trying to make my question simple to avoid a debate about how the table should have been designed in the first place. ;) If I could, I'd rewrite the "database" but there are over 10k lines filled with unique QuestName entries in the QuestData table. :( The way you outlined it would have been the way I would have organized the Key/Value pairs. Unfortunately, this was an inherited project and is already in "production". So, if I were to change it now, *smacks head* I can only imagine what kind of issues that would cause. I can only try and engineer around it...

Answer (score 1):

As Jakuje already mentioned table keys are unique.
But you can store both as a table member like:

```
   QuestData = {
    -- "QuestName" must be unique! Of course you can put it into a table member as well
    ["QuestName"]={
       {hash = "Quest Descrip", values = {8,1686192712} },
       {hash = "Quest Descrip", values = {32,1686193248} },
       {hash = "Quest Descrip", values = {0,2965579272} }

        }
    }
```

I'm sure you can organize this in a better way. It looks like a rather confusing concept to me.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. :) The "hash" number I'm after is the 10 digit number in the very last value. These numbers: 1686192712,  1686193248, and 2965579272.

Answer (score 1):

You've said you can't "rewrite the database", but the problem is the `QuestData` table doesn't hold what you think it holds.

Here's your table:

```
QuestData = {
    ["QuestName"]={
        ["Quest Descrip"]={8,1686192712},
        ["Quest Descrip"]={32,1686193248},
        ["Quest Descrip"]={0,2965579272},
    },
}
```

But, this is actually like writing...

```
QuestData["Quest Descrip"] = {8,1686192712}
QuestData["Quest Descrip"] = {32,1686193248}
QuestData["Quest Descrip"] = {0,2965579272}
```

So the second (and then, third) values overwrite the first. The problem is not that you can't access the table, but that the table doesn't contain the values any more.

You need to find a different way of representing your data.

Comment: *smacks head* You know what, you're right! I could create a separate table to hold the returned values like so...
`for kk,vv in pairs(v) do
  table.insert(...)
  index = index + 1
end`
...but while doing so make sure they are inserted with unique identifiers.

Comment: Actually. I played around with this for a bit. I inserted Print strings to see what was being spit out during the first `for kk,vv` loop under QuestName. It randomly picks only one of the duplicate "Quest Descrip" entries. I have no control over which one it picks but it picks the same one each time. So, it never iterates over all of them. I.E. each loop is printing the same thing. So a separate capture table doesn't work. Well it does but it only returns one entry. I can even spit out the table by index rather than by pairs and it still only shows one entry. :(

Comment: @Dyaxler. YOU CANNOT ITERATE OVER THINGS THAT DON'T EXIST! *There is only one entry in the table, not three*. Re-read Jakule's post, read the basics about Lua tables, because while you say "I know all that" you don't seem to understand any of it.

Comment: The original QuestData table is static not dynamic.In the example Quest I gave in my opening post, there are in fact 3 entries.But the "keys" aren't unique so LUA picks one of the three random ones.Using your idea I thought maybe it would pick a different "random" one each loop and I could insert those into another table in a different order with a unique key for each.Nope.It picks the same one each time so the idea didn't work.I know you can't iterate over non-existent data... it spits out a nil error otherwise. Not enough room to explain in greater detail but I do understand. :)

Comment: @Dyaxler. Please explain what you mean by "static" and "dynamic" tables. And can you show an example where Lua picks a "random one" rather than the last?